# Scraping Data is so slow

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am trying to **scrape** data using python and this is the code

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame()
key = 'a'

# Goes from 1 to 1000 (including both)
for value in range(1, 1001):
    url = "https://xxxxxxx.000webhostapp.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=%s&type=2&limit=%s" %(key, value)
    try:        
        r = requests.get(url)
        cont = json.loads(r.content)
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(cont)

        results = results.append(temp_df)
    except:
        continue

results.to_csv('en-a.csv', index=False)
```

the code works fine but the problem is that scrping data is so so slow , when i try to **scrape** data `for value in range(1, 11):` took 2 minutes to **scrape** the 10 pages and i'm planning to **scrape** `for value in range(1, 1001)` and that will take more than 2:30 hours , how i can fix that and **scrape** the data fast ?

Thank you

Comment: it depends on what you trying to find. Maybe little close regex could extract compact result with less time.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently making your requests synchronously - waiting for each one to complete before moving on to the next. Instead, you should fetch pages in parallel so that you can be downloading multiple pages at a time. Try something like this instead (which will fetch 10 pages at a time in parallel):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

def fetch(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    # Catch HTTP errors/exceptions here
    return(pd.DataFrame(json.loads(resp.content)))

results = pd.DataFrame()
key = 'a'
urls = ["https://xxxxxxx.000webhostapp.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=%s&type=2&limit=%s" %(key, value) 
        for value in range(1, 1001)]

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
for page in pool.map(fetch, urls):
    results.append(page)

results.to_csv('en-a.csv', index=False)
```

Depending on your network connection, and how many requests the server will allow you to make, you can increase the `max_workers=` argument for `ThreadPoolExecutor` to increase the number of parallel fetches.

There are also a variety of other ways you can get higher performance for parallel/concurrent fetches (asyncio/aiohttp is another common technique). But for what you're doing, the above is simple and effective enough - it will make your fetching (which is likely where your program is spending the large majority of its time) much, much faster.